# Code to do a "bit iterator" but with 3 states

Tags: python, math, syntax, logic

I am wanting to do a counter that iterates over 3 states.  I know how to do this for 2 states using the bit operator `i^=1`.

I want to know if there is a way to do similiar but with three states?

I realize I can just do:

```
i = 0
while
   if(i==3)
       i = 0
   do stuff here
   i++
```

But I was hoping for something more elegant and efficient.  I was thinking of a modulus trick or something.

(Right now I am using python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) be useful for you?

```
import itertools
states = itertools.cycle([0, 1, 2])
while True:
  i = states.next()
  <do stuff>
```

Comment: Yup, this is perfect.  I figured there was already a module object to do just this.  Thank you.  (I will leave the question still open to see if there is perhaps a language universal mathematical operation to do it).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in itertools.cycle([1,2,3]):
    target.set_state(i)
```

maybe??

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up mathematically and language independent.  For sets more than 3, I believe you need to change the prime and offsets.

```
i = 1
while
     do stuff
     i = 7%(3+(abs(i-3)))
```